# SSH Server cannot be found - Even though installed

Tags: ssh, openssh, sshd

I have a machine running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS where I cannot seem to get SSH Server working.

I installed SSHServer using:

```
sudo apt install openssh-server
```

but I am getting the following when I try to start and / or check the status:

```
sudo systemctl start sshd

Failed to start sshd.service: Unit sshd.service not found.
```

.

```
sudo systemctl status sshd

Unit sshd.service could not be found.
```

I figured I must have done something wrong (typo?) when I installed, so I tried to install again thus:

```
sudo apt install openssh-server
```

to which I get:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
openssh-server is already the newest version (1:7.6p1-4ubuntu0.3).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

So, it appears it is installed, but for some reason Ubuntu cannot find it.

I am not sure where to go from here, so any suggestions would be welcome.

Thanks,

Alan.

Comment: I followed [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/openssh-server.html) and it worked.

Comment: I think it is fixed by removing and reinstalling, but I have bookmarked the link to gave and will follow that next time I need to install ssh server.  Thanks!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It is possible that the service is not called sshd.
you can try this command

```
systemctl -l --type service --all|grep ssh
```

On my ubuntu 18.04, the service is called ssh by default.

in my case, I did

```
sudo systemctl start ssh
```

If that doesn't solve your problem, you can reinstall ssh

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge openssh-server
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install openssh-server
```